# Parameter of PageAdapter not updated on NotificationDataSetChanged

Tags: android, adapter

I create an application where i need to send data to a RecyclerView on a ViewPager, this data is some json query from an api.

The "onResult" of my retrofit say the data is correctly query, so no problem here.

But when i update ma ViewPager adapter the data from the variable is not updated, what ever i do. Any idea ?

1. I tried to put the viewpager.setAdapter([...]) on the onResult, after the variable intiate.
2. I initiate my self the variable just before the setAdapter, here it worked.
   (so the travel of the variable data is ok)
3. When i Log.d() the variable initiated with retrofit data, it's shown.

> MainFragment

```
List<News> news = new ArrayList<>();

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable iewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...
    pager.setAdapter(new PageAdapter(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager(),
            pageTitles,
            news));
        ...
}

@Override
public void onResult(List<News> news) {
    this.news = news; // At this step news contain 12 elements of type news.
    pager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

> PageAdapter

```
    ...
@Override
public int getItemPosition(@NonNull Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
    ...
```

Right now when i log on the adapter after update, the variable is still empty.

I just want my data to pass througt the adapter after update on onResult ^^.

> Just below the entire class of MainFragment and the adapter

*-----------------------------------*

> Main fragment

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements NewsAsyncTask.Listeners{

ViewPager pager;
List<News> news = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> pageTitles = new ArrayList<>();

public MainFragment(){}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    pager = (ViewPager) result.findViewById(R.id.main_viewpager);

    new NewsAsyncTask(this).execute("JakeWharton");

    pageTitles.add(getString(R.string.page_title_topstories));
    pageTitles.add(getString(R.string.page_title_mostpopular));
    pageTitles.add(getString(R.string.page_title_favorites));

    News test = new News();
    test.setTitle("TEST");

    news.add(test);

    Log.d("[********]",news.get(0).getTitle());

    pager.setAdapter(new PageAdapter(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager(),
            pageTitles,
            news));

    TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) result.findViewById(R.id.main_tablayout);

    tabs.setupWithViewPager(pager);

    tabs.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);

    return result;
}

@Override
public void onResult(List<News> news) {
    this.news = news;
    pager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

> PageAdapter

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    private final ArrayList<String> pageTitle;
    private List<News> news;

    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<String> pageTitle, List<News> news) {
        super(fm);

        this.pageTitle = pageTitle;
        this.news = news;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return PageFragment.newInstance(news);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pageTitle.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(@NonNull Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return pageTitle.get(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: why return type is POSITION_NONE? it should be size of list.

Comment: Because it allow the adapter to be updated on NotificationDataSetChanged.

Comment: you don't get my point. kindly share whole code of adapter and fragment.

Comment: There it is ! I've edited the code

Comment: It won't work, that's crazy dude ...